# Alternative to strange BSA BB

Tags: bottom-bracket

Left  on the picture new shimano 68x122 mm BSA BB. Right one was installed on my bike. It's written there: JIVE 3.0 128K 123. The spindle is 128 mm.
I've mesuared BB tube, it's 68mm. It has also a mount for chain guard. So, it adds 2 mm on the drive side.

Looking on the picture it seems to be the same chain line with both BB. But non drive side is much shorter with shimano. The latter has also shorter body. Could you explain that? Should I reorder 127 mm shimano BB?

UPD
It is not assymetrical BB. They have longer spindle on the drive side. In my case it seems to be longer on non-drive side.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace asymmetrical BB with symmetrical cartridge and spacers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/replace-asymmetrical-bb-with-symmetrical-cartridge-and-spacers)

Comment: It looks to me like the threaded piece is not a part of the cartridge, but is removable??  And the spindle is not longer, relative to the cartridge body, but rather the cartridge body is longer?